# Custom Right-click Context Menu verb / contextMenuHandler in Windows 8 Registry no longer works for AutoCAD .dwg file

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, context-menu, autocad, dwg

I am currently having a problem when it comes to adding a right click context menu verb whenever the user right clicks on a ".dwg" file in Windows 8. I do not spend a lot of time in the registry and I am sure there is something small I could possibly be overlooking. I have been able to add this action to the AutoCAD drawing file in previous Windows OS and versions of AutoCAD until Windows 8-8.1. I have installed multiple versions of AutoCAD on Windows 8 and have not been able to create the action for ".dwg". However, I am able to add this verb to Excel files and CSVs in Windows 8.

Our standard approach was to use shellex/ContextMenuHandlers/GUID of the program I am trying to launch on right click.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AutoCAD.Drawing.20\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{1e25bcd5-f299-496a-911d-51fb901f7f40}
```

I have tried manually editing the registry key for the ".dwg" files using shell/verb/command structure and have had no success with ".dwg" in Windows 8. I am able to use the shell/verb/command entry for ".xls" and ".csv" files in Windows 8 and it works.

I am looking for a push in the right direction as to what might have changed for this not to work. I have read as much as I could find on Registry changes for Windows 8.  I am also posting this on the AutoCAD forums for help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way it has always worked:

1. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dwg` and note the **(Default)** value which will be the ProgID (something like *dwgfile* for example).
2. Under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ProgID` create the appropriate sub-keys and values:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dwgfile\shell\opendwg]
   @="Open with My Program"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\dwgfile\shell\opendwg\command]
   @="\"C:\\Program Files\\My Program\\MyProgram.exe\" \"%1\""
   ```

Comment: I am sorry that I did not make it clear, but I have already tried to do that. I added the appropriate sub-keys and values for the extensions that I wanted and the only extension that does not work is the .dwg. The ProgID is AutoCAD.drawing20 or AutoCAD.drawing19 in my case where I added the values. I tried both using the shellex context menu and the shell command.

Comment: Well that is the way it's supposed to work, so without taking a look at your registry I can't really suggest anything else.

Comment: I appreciate your help.